# Racket macro that recursively processes a list argument

Tags: recursion, macros, scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a macro that recursively 'unwraps' the values of a list into individual values. For example, `unwrap '(1 2 3))` would produce (separately):

```lisp
(car '(1 2 3)) ; 1
(car (cdr '(1 2 3)) ; 2
(car (cdr (cdr '(1 2 3)) ; 3
```

This would be used like `(+ (unwrap '(1 2 3)))` ==> `(+ 1 2 3)`. (I know you can use the standard libary apply for this, but I'm trying to write my own version).

My problem is that in writing the macro, I don't know how to recursively process the list argument passed into the unwrap macro. Here's what I've tried:

```lisp
(define-syntax (unwrap stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ lst)
      #`(begin (car lst) ; error at the last step since (car '()) is invalid
               (unwrap (cdr lst)))]))
```

or

```lisp
(define-syntax (unwrap stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ lst)
      #`(if (null? lst)
            '()
            (car (unwrap (cdr lst))))])) ; infinite loops
```

These are both obviously wrong, but essentially I don't know write a macro that check the value of the input list (or matches against an empty list pattern) and returns something different in either scenario. It's also possible I'm approaching this entirely wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
(+ (unwrap '(1 2 3))) ==> (+ 1 2 3)
```

but this is impossible. You are asking for `unwrap` to macroexpand to three disconnected forms, which is not allowed. Any macro must expand into exactly one form. So as you say in your question, for the example you gave, `apply` is the right answer.

For other possible usages, the answer is to back up a step and ask why you think this `unwrap` function would be useful: what cases do you hope to use it in? Then design a different solution, that works within the constraints of the language.

Comment: I see. I had a feeling it was not possible to expand in that way, but I didn't know enough about macros to confirm my suspicions. Thank you.